Firebase Realtime Database Error "Operation Canceled" Causes Observers to Stop Receiving Updates in Xcode 15.3
I'm developing an iOS application using Xcode 15.3 and Firebase SDK 11.3.0. My app utilizes Firebase Realtime Database to monitor changes in foodEntries through Firebase observers.
Here's a simplified overview of my implementation:
Setting Up Observers: I set up Firebase observers to listen for changes in the foodEntries node. This allows my app to react in real-time to any additions or modifications.
Monitoring Connection Status: I check the Firebase connection status whenever the app becomes active. Additionally, I track the network connection using NWPathMonitor to handle connectivity changes.
Issue: When I send the app to the background and then bring it back to the foreground, I occasionally encounter the following error in the console. This happens approximately once in ten attempts:

2024-10-10 17:49:08.588502+0200 MyApp[22614:2112636]
[[FirebaseDatabase]] 11.3.0 - [FirebaseDatabase][I-RDB083016] Error
sending web socket data: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=89
"Operation canceled" UserInfo={NSDescription=Operation canceled}.

Consequences: Once this error occurs, my app stops receiving updates from the Firebase observers. The observers' closure callbacks are no longer triggered, effectively halting real-time data synchronization. Additionally, the Firebase connection status change is not triggered when this happens.
Temporary Workaround: Interestingly, the issue resolves itself when I send the app to the background and then bring it back to the foreground. This action seems to reset the Firebase connection, allowing observers to function correctly again until the error reoccurs.
What I've Tried:
Reinitializing Observers: Attempted to remove and re-add observers upon detecting connection issues.
Connection Monitoring: Implemented NWPathMonitor to track network changes and attempt reconnections.
Error Handling: Tried catching errors during data operations to trigger retries or reconnections.
Despite these efforts, the Operation canceled error persists and disrupts the observer functionality.
Sample Code:
Here's how I set up the Firebase observers and monitor the network connection:
import FirebaseDatabase
import Network
import Combine

class UserData: ObservableObject {
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    private let networkQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkMonitor")
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    @Published var isAppFirebaseConnected: Bool = false
    @Published var isAppNetworkConnected: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        setupFirebaseMonitoring()
        startNetworkMonitoring()
    }
    
    private func setupFirebaseMonitoring() {
        let db = Database.database().reference()
        let connectedRef = db.child(".info/connected")
        
        connectedRef.observe(.value) { [weak self] snapshot in
            if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.isAppFirebaseConnected = connected
                    if connected {
                        print("Firebase is connected.")
                        // Initialize observers here
                        self?.initObservers()
                    } else {
                        print("Firebase is disconnected.")
                        self?.removeObservers()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func startNetworkMonitoring() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            let isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.isAppNetworkConnected = isConnected
                print("Network connection status: \(isConnected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected")")
                
                if isConnected && self?.isAppFirebaseConnected == false {
                    // Attempt to reconnect Firebase if needed
                    self?.reconnectFirebase()
                }
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: networkQueue)
    }
    
    private func initObservers() {
        let db = Database.database().reference()
        db.child("foodEntries").observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
            // Handle new food entry
            print("New food entry added: \(snapshot.key)")
        }
        
        db.child("foodEntries").observe(.childChanged) { snapshot in
            // Handle updated food entry
            print("Food entry updated: \(snapshot.key)")
        }
    }
    
    private func removeObservers() {
        let db = Database.database().reference()
        db.child("foodEntries").removeAllObservers()
        print("Removed all Firebase observers.")
    }
    
    private func reconnectFirebase() {
        print("Attempting to reconnect Firebase...")
        Database.database().goOffline()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            Database.database().goOnline()
        }
    }
}

Problem Description:
Observers Stop Working: After some time, the Operation canceled error appears, and the Firebase observers stop receiving updates.
No Triggered Closures: The closure callbacks for .childAdded and .childChanged are no longer invoked.
Manual Reset Required: Backgrounding and foregrounding the app temporarily fixes the issue by resetting the Firebase connection.
Question:
How can I prevent the NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=89 "Operation canceled" error from disrupting Firebase Realtime Database observers in my SwiftUI app using Xcode 15.3 and Firebase SDK 11.3.0?
Additionally, how can I effectively track and handle network connectivity changes to ensure that Firebase observers remain functional without requiring manual app state resets?
What I Need Help With:
Understanding the Cause: Insights into why the Operation canceled error occurs and how it affects Firebase's WebSocket connections.
Robust Error Handling: Best practices for handling such network-related errors to maintain continuous observer functionality.
Network Monitoring Integration: Examples or suggestions on effectively integrating network monitoring to trigger Firebase reconnections when necessary.
Alternative Solutions: Any alternative approaches or configurations that can mitigate this issue.
Additional Information:
Firebase Configuration: I'm using default Firebase configurations and have enabled offline persistence.
Device Environment: The issue occurs on both simulators and physical devices with stable internet connections.
App Lifecycle Management: Observers are set up when the app becomes active and removed when it resigns active, as shown in the sample code.
Any guidance or examples on handling this Firebase connection error and maintaining observer reliability would be greatly appreciated!

Investigation documented at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/13877
